# Migrating from CARTO Editor TO CARTO Builder and problem with odyssey.js (viz.json)

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js, odyssey-js

In odyssey.js you have:

-vizjson: URL like this "//username.cartodb.com/u/usernanme/api/v2/viz/key/viz.json"

The first thing we want to do is bring the CartoDB Visualization we created into the Odyssey.js application. We're going to use this vizjson option in the config block of your Odyssey.js markdown.

But now we cannot get this vizjson URL from cartDB!

The CARTO Builder does not have the option to share the viz.json URL due to the current version of CARTO.js (v3.15) which is not compatible with the Builder.

see:  [https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder](https://web.archive.org/web/20170125205945/https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder)

MIGRATING FROM CARTO EDITOR TO CARTO BUILDER:

Can I use CARTO Editor and CARTO Builder at the same time?

*No, once CARTO Builder is enabled for your account, it is the only available map application.*

Can I choose to use CARTO Editor instead?

*No, CARTO Editor is currently in the process of being deprecated. All of the Editor features, and additional advanced functionality, is available within CARTO Builder. Once CARTO Builder is enabled for your account, the CARTO Editor is no longer available.*

**All new accounts have CARTO BUILDER enabled...
If somebody could help me with an old account (for example without datasets/maps), it will be nice.**

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the viz.json by taking the key from the vizualisation link or url:
*//username.carto.com/u/username/builder/**key**/embed*

and appending it in the following format:
*//username.cartodb.com/u/usernanme/api/v2/viz/**key**/viz.json*

Currently, however, this will not contain legend info.
A bit of a hack, but it should do the trick for now, while we wait for the updated CARTO.js library:

> Viz.json / CARTO.js   The current version of CARTO.js is not compatible
>   with Builder. If you have a dependency on using CARTO.js, use the
>   Editor with the existing CARTO.js library.
>
> Note: An updated CARTO.js
>   library (version 4.0) is being developed to support all the new
>   Builder functionality, and will be available soon.
>
> Source:
>   https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations

Comment: You can do that, but legends, popups and of course, widgets generated from BUILDER will not appear on your map. But geometries (from analysis) and colors (from Turbo CARTO) will do. Because Odyssey is based on CARTO.js v3 you can add programmatically/manually custom infowindows and legends. And of course, another solution is to build a vizjson v2 from the ground up.